# Footer menu "drop-up-menu" to display above

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menubar

> *I got it myself and wanted to leave this for later people having the same question. So no need to waste your precious time answering this question.*

OK, so I have a fixed bottom menu bar. It has a popup menu and it's currently not hidden at any point because it is not necessary yet. This bar is fixed in the bottom of the page and it has a popup box. The problem is that I can't get the **popup placed above** the actual button.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="quickBar">
    <div id="menuCont">

        <div id="quickBarMenu">
            <p>Navigation</p>
            <ul>
                <li><p>Articles</p></li>
                <li><p>Blog</p></li>
                <li><p>Software</p></li>
                <li><p>Featured</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#quickBar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    display: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(59,70,71,0.4) 0%,rgba(59,70,71,0.4) 45%,rgba(59,70,71,0.2) 55%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(59,70,71,0.4) 0%,rgba(59,70,71,0.4) 45%,rgba(59,70,71,0.2) 55%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(59,70,71,0.4) 0%,rgba(59,70,71,0.4) 45%,rgba(59,70,71,0.2) 55%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(59,70,71,0.4) 0%,rgba(59,70,71,0.4) 45%, rgba(59,70,71,0.2) 55%);
    opacity: 0.95;
    display: none;
}

#quickBar > #menuCont{
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
}

#menuCont > div{
    float: left;
}

#quickBarMenu{
    width: 183px;
}

#quickBarMenu p{
    width: 183px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
}

#quickBarMenu > ul{
    /*display: none;*/
    list-style: none;
}
```

I hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: You have `bottom: 0;` in the bar. What do you think it might do to other elements too?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it myself by using a negative margin of `margin-top` with the value `-200px` (4 x 50px).